# EOF not recognized

Tags: c, windows-10

I have a program that is supposed to get input from a user until it receives `EOF`.

`\n` or white spaces are considered as legal chars,
but the console recognizes neither `^z` nor `^d` as `EOF` and the program continues to run until stopped manually.

Tried both:

```
while (currChar != EOF)
{
scanf("%c", &currChar);
}
```

and:

```
scanf("%c", &currChar);
if (currChar==EOF)
 break;
```

Comment: Relevant to the problem - [Why is `while ( !feof(file) )` is always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Also what is the type of `currChar` ?

Comment: Thanks @user3121023, this fixed is

Comment: Something that needs to be emphasized is that in the context of C I/O routines, there's no end-of-file *character* like a newline or backspace or other control character.  It's not something that's read from the stream.  It's a *condition* that's set by the I/O routine when a read fails due to being at the end of the file - basically, a flag in the `FILE` object is set to indicate that there's no more input.  The I/O routines return `EOF` as an *error code*.

Comment: windows 10 is irrelevent to your problem, please remove that tag

Comment: FYI, if ^Z is the first character of a line read from the console, `ReadFile` sets the number of bytes read to 0, but only if the console is in processed-input mode (enabled by default). Note that if you set `stdin` to Unicode text mode via `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT)` and switch to using `wscanf`, then the console is read via `ReadConsoleW`, which does not implement this ^Z behavior. Instead it's the standard I/O in the Windows C runtime that looks for ^Z, just like when reading a disk file in text mode. But neither the console nor the Windows CRT implement ^D to terminate a read.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf()` doesn't set the variable to `EOF` when it gets to the end of the input, it *returns* `EOF`. So you have to test the value of the function.

```
while (scanf("%c", &currChar) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In general, if there are `n` conversions in the `scanf()`, the best test is `while (scanf("…", …) == n)` which detects EOF _and_ conversion failures.  With a single `%c` conversion, the EOF test works because you'll either get 1 or EOF, but with a conversion such as `%d`, you can get `0` returned (because the next character that's not white space is also not a digit or a sign).

Comment: If you also want to check for conversion failures, you would ideally assign the return value to a variable and check for that separately.

Comment: Yes.  And if you want to reparse the input, then you use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` and parse with `sscanf()` instead of `scanf()`, so that if there's a problem with the input, you can either try again with a different format string or report the error more sanely.  (The list goes on… :D)

Answer (score 0):

Well, `EOF` is not a character. It's an integer constant with the value of `-1`. With that said if you enter with the value of `EOF`, your `char` variable would read only the `-` (minus) from `-1` value. That's why the loop won't stop, they'll never be equal.